# Как передать Request Headers что бы получить json

Tags: php, api, url, requests

Есть API, которое возвращает информацию в соответствии с передаваемыми заголовками (Reauest Headers). Нужно выполнить запрос:

`Request URL https://b2bapi.api.ru/b2b/api/v1/user/reports/akk_tr_report_tehkharakteristiki_test/_make`

и с этим запросом передать заголовки для того что бы получить в ответ нужную мне инфу. Заголовок такого вида:

```
{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "AR-REST YWtiY2VOTk5OnJververqoUVE9PQ=="
}
```

Возможно ли это как то реализовать?

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: AR-REST YWtiY2VudHJkdkBrewfeM2MzQ3MjM6OTk5OTk5OTk5OnJoRm1kbEFrdz2JoUVE9PQ==' -d '{ \ 
   "queryType": "GRZ", \ 
   "query": "А111СО27" \ 
 }' 'https://b2bapi.api.ru/b2b/api/v1/user/reports/akkr_tr_report_tehkharakteristiki_test/_make'
```

Comment: А в чём сложность?

Comment: Не понятно решение, гуглил, не нашел... Как передать зоголовок вместе с http запросом

Comment: @Какой метод запроса? GET POST PUT и так далее? И чем пользуетесь, curl, pecl, httpRequets и т.п.?

Comment: POST CURL в вопросе написал какой курл

Comment: Вы уверены, что url рабочий?

Comment: https://b2bapi.avtocod.ru/swagger-ui.html#/user - там POST запрос, при вводе в поле токена и REPORT_TYPE_UID мы на выходе получаем Curl
Request URL
Request Headers
Response Body,  Response Body это json, в котором нужные данные

Comment: Curl формируется из введенных данных в makeReportRequest, Authorization, REPORT_TYPE_UID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$Param1 = "GRZ";
$Param2 = "А111СО27";
$AuthToken = 'AR-REST YWtiY2VudHJkdkBrewfeM2MzQ3MjM6OTk5OTk5OTk5OnJoRm1kbEFrdz2JoUVE9PQ==';
$Request = '{
   "queryType": "' . $Param1 . '",
   "query": "' . $Param2 . '" 
 }';


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://b2bapi.avtocod.ru/b2b/api/v1/user/reports/default/_make",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$Request",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: $AuthToken",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Вы только свой токен вставьте, потому что у этого токена ответ `Неверная структура токена авторизации` - `"token": "AR-REST YWtiY2VudHJkdkBrewfeM2MzQ3MjM6OTk5OTk5OTk5OnJoRm1kbEFrdz2JoUVE9PQ==",` `Last unit does not have enough valid bits`

Comment: Да, конечно, вставил свой, но в ответ получил:   {"success":false,"error":{"uid":"c5f6cd055fa2422802e249f","timestamp":"1579543596337","code":"G001","class":"Global","type":"NotImplementedCommand","name":"Не реализованная команда API","message":"Данная команда не поддерживается AVTORAPORT API (v1) : /user/reports/akk_istiki_test/make","data":{"api_version":1,"route":"/user/reports/akkfw_tr_report_tehkharakteristiki_test/make"}}}

Comment: @Ilyaaa521 Пардон, url другой - `https://b2bapi.avtocod.ru/b2b/api/v1/user/reports/default/_make` изменил в ответе.

Comment: Еще вопросик, могу ли я меня и добавлять свои значения в CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? Мне нужно добавлять свои значения в \"query\": \"А111СО27\" \n, не А111СО27 а любое другое.

Comment: $gos = $_POST['gos'];
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n   \"queryType\": \"GRZ\",\n   \"query\": \"$gos\" \n }" К примеру вот так вот

Comment: @Ilyaaa521 Добавил в ответ как проще будет )

Comment: Можно Вам еще вопрос задать? Почти с интегрировал API, немного не получается завершить

Comment: @Ilyaaa521 Да, давайте.

Comment: Сделал в этом же файле-обработчике еще один Curl, только не POST а GET, почему то что бы он сработал нужно повторно отрпавить форму в обработчик...

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Не должно такого быть. Выложите Ваш запрос.

Comment: Разобрался, это апи такое, там интервал между GET и POST должен быть не менее 5 сек, поставил между ними sleep(5) и все заработало )